# Advanced query with mongodb with several conditions

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

My mongodb document contains object `CarData` with several properties inside.

```
{
   _id: ...,
   Name: "",
   CarData: {
     carId: null,
     ownerName: "",
     ownerPhone: "",
     AdditionalInfo:{
       RefNr: ""
       validDoc: true
    }
   }
}
```

I know I can query the whole collection

```
{ "CarData": { $exists: true } }
```

but I don't know how to query whole collection with

```
CarData exists and is not null 
and ownerName != "" 
and AdditionalInfo exists and  != null 
and AdditionalInfo.validDoc == true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In mongo you don't need to check if the fields exist before checking internal properties. I think this should be enought for you. [Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/oGvuu2DD1NR)

```
db.collection.find({
  "CarData.ownerName": {
    "$ne": ""
  },
  "CarData.AdditionalInfo.validDoc": true
})
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the documents as per your specification. you have to use [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) provided by MongoDB. The query below will fulfill your requirements.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "$and": [
        {
          CarData: {
            "$exists": true
          }
        },
        {
          CarData: {
            "$ne": null
          }
        },
        {
          "CarData.ownerName": {
            $ne: ""
          }
        },
        {
          $and: [
            {
              "CarData.AdditionalInfo": {
                "$exists": true
              }
            },
            {
              "CarData.AdditionalInfo": {
                "$ne": null
              }
            },
            {
              "CarData.AdditionalInfo.validDoc": true
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

The above query will give the list of documents with the matching condition.